# Filtering off ID column - CQWP

Tags: content-query-web-part

I am displaying two filtered views of a SharePoint (pages) library - one view is showing the `3 most recent article pages` and another one `showing all the rest/archive` (therefore not showing the same most recent three articles).

I cannot get the "archive" view to work correctly. Ideally, it would show all but the highest 3 numeric ID numbers since those are already displayed in the list view right next to it.

> Does anyone have a formula to filter off all but the highest 3 ID numbers?

Answer (score 0):

I have tested "Show items when ID is less than `[PageQueryString:totalPageNumber]-3` in CQWP and it works.

But this does not really solve your problem. The work around will be to append total pages number into your URL, sort items based on the Created, and show items when ID is less than totalPageNumber -3

Again, this will work but not the most ideal/elegant solution.